# HTML Syntax error in eclipse for angular directives - Attribute name must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: angular, eclipse-mars, angular-ui-pagination

Hi i am facing a strange issue here. I am trying to apply angular pagination in my application. I am trying to implement the code example [given](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)
I added everything perfectly.My application is in java spring framework.  My code is below. I am running the code in eclipse mars.My Error is

> Attribute name "uib-pagination" associated with an element type "ul" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

```
<div class="imt_paginationCtr">     
   <ul uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" num-pages="numPages"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS FILE**

```
var app=angular.module('formvalid', [ 'ui.utils','ngAnimate','ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('validationCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.totalItems = 64;
        $scope.currentPage = 4;

        $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
            $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
        };

        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
        $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
});
```

I am not able to understand the issue. Where i am doing the mistakes?

**ERROR display in browser**

> Mon Mar 19 14:32:27 IST 2018
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Exception parsing document: template="workflow", line 256 - column 52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Eclipse is not smart enough to recognize those directives. You can either disable the HTML validation
by going to `Preferences -> Validation` and uncheck the checkboxes for HTML as per the below image.

[image]

Or you can allow those directives from `Web -> HTML Files -> Validation` and add the directives to be allowed in the highlighted input box.

[image]

If your open to other editors, try [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for your JS/UI stuff.

Comment: In my eclipse prefence scereen i am not able to find the `WEB` or `validator`  to disable the functionalities.

Comment: @PranavMS Updated the answer with steps. Please let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: I have tried everything but it is not working in my case. Even i uninstalled my eclipse and installed newer version.

Comment: is there is any other way to avoid this issue?